# Generating random data from database in php with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to generate random question from the database, there is module wise and marks assigned to every question so, if  question asked for 1 marks, number of question is two and module selected Module1,Module2 and Module3 then it should fetch 2 random question from all the three Module. but here its showing 2-2 question from each module

```
<?php 
    if($rr2['pmod1'] == 1){
        $setmod = 1;

    $qqr1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE qsub='$esub' AND qmarks='$marksperquestion' AND qmod='$setmod' LIMIT $noofquestion");
    while($rrr1 = mysql_fetch_array($qqr1)){
        if($rr2)
        echo '<tr class="gradeX">';
        echo '<td>'.$rrr1['qquestion'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $qqid = $rrr1['qid'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO finalpaper VALUES('', '$portionss', '$qqid', '0')");
    }
    }
    if($rr2['pmod'] == 1){
        $setmod = 2;
    $qqr1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE qsub='$esub' AND qmarks='$marksperquestion' AND qmod='$setmod' LIMIT $noofquestion");
    while($rrr1 = mysql_fetch_array($qqr1)){
        if($rr2)
        echo '<tr class="gradeX">';
        echo '<td>'.$rrr1['qquestion'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $qqid = $rrr1['qid'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO finalpaper VALUES('', '$portionss', '$qqid', '0')");
    }
    }
    if($rr2['pmod3'] == 1){
        $setmod = 3;
    $qqr1 =$qqr1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE qsub='$esub' AND qmarks='$marksperquestion' AND qmod='$setmod' LIMIT $noofquestion");
    while($rrr1 = mysql_fetch_array($qqr1)){
        if($rr2)
        echo '<tr class="gradeX">';
        echo '<td>'.$rrr1['qquestion'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $qqid = $rrr1['qid'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO finalpaper VALUES('', '$portionss', '$qqid', '0')");
    }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql `RAND()` function.

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

Note: This is a simple query that will clear the idea.

Apply your business logic (conditions for fetching 2 questions for each module in WHERE clause).

Comment: SELECT *  FROM  `question` WHERE qsub =2 AND qmarks =  '1' AND qmod =1 ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 0 , 1

this is working... but I am stucked how to select module.